# How to delete/move to trash a desktop shortcut as context menu Move to Trash is greyed

Tags: shortcuts

I got a Desktop Shortcut for "Network Servers" which launch a Nautilus Network window. I don't know why this shortcut appeared in the first place. However I would like to get rid of it. Right clicking on the shortcut shows that the option "Move to Trash" is greyed, highlighting a permission problem?

This option is greyed may be because I am not considered as Root (by default in Ubuntu). However I don't know where the file is and therefore can't change its permission. Can I get rid of that shortcut in a terminal ? where is the file to remove ? Can I tell Ubuntu that I am Root to allow the Move to Trash option in the context menu ?

It looks like Desktop shortcuts management is a hell in Ubuntu 11.10 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type this to hide the shortcut

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop network-icon-visible false
```

Your desktop should not display the icon for the *Network Severs* after this.

Comment: Unfortunately The Home Desktop is empty in Nautilus even after selecting View hidden files...

Comment: Whatever. Nautilus does not show any files in ~/Desktop even as stated earlier after selecting View Hidden Files. Opening Nautilus as root as suggested doesn't change anything whatsoever. Hence your solution does not work.
I would like to know where this shortcut is placed in the /... tree in order to attempt a removal. Obviously it is not placed in Home Desktop.

Comment: There you go, anything else add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed after 2 hours to find a solution. :)
I was prevented for 8 hours to post it.

1. Install [GNOME Tweak Tool](http://apt://gnome-tweak-tool) also called *Advanced Settings* in the Dash from Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Launch *Advanced Settings* from the Dash.
3. Select *Desktop* and just Turn Off *Network Servers* visible on the Desktop.
4. That's it. No more Launcher for Network Servers on my Unity Desktop.

I still don't know how this Desktop Launcher/Shorcut was activated on my Ubuntu 11.10.

Also, the command line solution `gsettings` ... does work as well. As it is too modifying the settings of the gnome.

Another GUI solution is to use dconf Editor, navigating to `org` → `gnome` → `nautilus` → `desktop` and to uncheck the *network-icon-visible* parameter.

Comment: did bruno's command work for you?  It should have worked - it sounds very similar to yours.  Please tick one of the answers to close this question.